# Add new city onselect of 'Other' option in dropdown in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, geolocation

I am implementing geo-location table using SQL Server.
I have added major country, states and cities in database, but I want to allow adding values by selecting '**Other**' option in drop down. If I select '**other**' in country, then same option should be selected in state and city dropdowns. It should also show additional textboxes for each dropdown.
I am using asp.net 3.5, database is sql server 2008 using linq. Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you fill your dropdowns with values from the database, you should add one more:'Other...' with the value of 'other', it should be placed at the end of the lists.
Also, you should place one hidden textbox for each dropdown:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server" Style="display:none;"></asp:TextBox>
```

On the client side, you can use jQuery or javascript to catch when user select this value. There should be three functions: 'other country' shows all three textboxes, 'other state' shows two and 'other city' shows only one:

```
$('#countries').change(function() {
    var country= $("#states option:selected").text();
    if(country == 'other') {
        var country = $("#countries option:selected").val();
    if (country === 'other') {
        $("#states").val('other');
        $("#cities").val('other');

        $("#txtCountry").show();
        $("#txtState").show();
        $("#txtCity").show();
   }
   else {
       //if user select 'other' and later select something else, you should hide textbox
       $("#txtCountry").hide();
   }

});
```

In the same way, create functions for States and Cities.

After this, at the code behind you can check if selected values are 'other', then use value from the textboxes. I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#states').change(function() {
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
    var value = $(this).val();
       if(value == '')
       {
         // change other city drop down 
         var newOption = $('<option value="">Other</option>');
         $('#city').append(newOption);
       }
 });
```